# How to remove black background color for Quill codeblocks

Tags: quill

When you enter a code block in the Quill editor, you get white text on a black background for that code block. How do you remove this styling? I'd rather have my normal black font color with a lighter background color.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the theme you use, you will find the settings in the according CSS file, e.g., `quill.snow.css` or `quill.bubble.css`:

```
.ql-snow .ql-editor pre.ql-syntax {
  background-color: #23241f; /* <== change this color */ 
  color: #f8f8f2;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quill's syntax highlighting is using [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) so you can just use a different theme that is more to your liking. If you would like to disable syntax highlighting altogether then you should omit the syntax module on initialization:

```
new Quill(container, {
  modules: {
    // syntax: true    Don't add me
  }
});
```